# Asymptotic scaling of standard Gaussian pdf and cdf

Tags: asymptotics, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

**Setup:** Let us denote the pdf and cdf functions of the standard Gaussian distribution by $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ respectively. What are the asymptotic scalings of both of them (in terms of their inputs)? I can get the pdf's scaling but not the cdf's scaling.

**My attempt:** For the pdf, we have
\begin{align*}
\phi(x)
=\frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
=\Theta(\exp(-x^2/2)).
\end{align*}
So for example, if $x=\Theta((\log n)^{1/2})$, then $\phi(x)=n^{-1/2}$.

**Question:** What about the cdf? The definition of the cdf has an integration, making it hard to simplify. If the big-$\Theta$ scaling is not possible, then any tight upper bound (big-$O$ scaling) also works. Thanks. I would prefer something simple that avoids the use of the erf functions.

**Related work:** This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921652/estimate-fraction-of-standard-normal-pdfand-standard-normal-cdf-frac-varphix) provided something simple for $x>0$, I am looking for something similar but for general $x$ or $x\leq0$.